# Adjust function of pure js carousel

Tags: javascript

I have following pure js simple carousel:
https://codepen.io/gety9/pen/eGEBmm

**HTML:**

```
<div class="slider-container">
    <!-- nav arrows -->
    <div class="slider-arrows">
        <div class="slider-arrow-left arrowLeft">
            <svg width="16" height="30" class="svg-arrow">
                <polyline style="stroke-linejoin:miter; stroke:#00275a; stroke-width:3; fill: none;" points="15 2, 2 15, 15 28" />
              </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="slider-arrow-right arrowRight">
            <svg width="16" height="30" class="svg-arrow">
                <polyline style="stroke-linejoin:miter; stroke:#00275a; stroke-width:3; fill: none;" points="2 2, 14 15, 2 28" />
              </svg>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="frame">
        <div id="slider">
            <!-- Box start -->
            <div class="slider-box slide">
                <div class="slider-photo">
                    <a href="#">
              <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x150/ff000"/>
            </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Box end -->
            <!-- Box start -->
            <div class="slider-box slide">
                <div class="slider-photo">
                    <a href="#">
              <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x150"/>
            </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Box end -->
            <!-- Box start -->
            <div class="slider-box slide">
                <div class="slider-photo">
                    <a href="#">
              <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x150/00ff00"/>
            </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Box end -->
            <!-- Box start -->
            <div class="slider-box slide">
                <div class="slider-photo">
                    <a href="#">
              <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x150"/>
            </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Box end -->
            <!-- Box start -->
            <div class="slider-box slide">
                <div class="slider-photo">
                    <a href="#">
              <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x150/0000ff"/>
            </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Box end -->
            <!-- Box start -->
            <div class="slider-box slide">
                <div class="slider-photo">
                    <a href="#">
              <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x150"/>
            </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Box end -->
            <!-- Box start -->
            <div class="slider-box slide">
                <div class="slider-photo">
                    <a href="#">
              <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x150/ffff00"/>
            </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Box end -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.slider-container {
  width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto;
}
#frame {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.slider {
  position: relative;
  transition: 500ms;
  display: inline-flex;
}
.slide {
  display: inline-block;
}
.slider-arrow-left {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: -20px;
}
.slider-arrow-right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: -20px;
}
.svg-arrow:hover{
    opacity:0.6;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

**JS**

```
var Carousel = function (frameSelector, sliderSelector, slidesSelector, btnLeftSelector, btnRightSelector) {
    //A variable to store the position of the slides
    var leftPosition = 0;
    var frame = document.querySelector(frameSelector);
    var slides = document.querySelectorAll(slidesSelector);
    //Get the number of slides in the slider
    var slidesNumber = slides.length;
    var leftButton = document.querySelector(btnLeftSelector);
    var rightButton = document.querySelector(btnRightSelector);
    var slider = document.querySelector(sliderSelector);

    //Add classes to frame and slider divs
    frame.classList.add('frame');
    slider.classList.add('slider');

    //Event listeners for when the user clicks on the arrows
    leftButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
        carousel.previous();
    });

    rightButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
        carousel.next();
    });

    //Function that moves the slides left or right depending on variable value
    //Moves to the next slide if value is -1, moves to the previous is value is 1
    var moveSlide = function (value) {
        leftPosition += value*250;
        slider.style.left = leftPosition + 'px';
    };

    return {
        //Function to move to next slide
        next: function() {
            if(leftPosition > (slidesNumber-1)*-250)
            {
                moveSlide(-1);
            } else {
                leftPosition = 0;
                slider.style.left = leftPosition + 'px';
            }
        },
        //Function to go to previous slide
        previous: function() {
            if(leftPosition !== 0) {
                 moveSlide(1);
            } else {
                leftPosition = (slidesNumber-1)*-250;
                slider.style.left = leftPosition + 'px';
            }
        }
    };
};

//Create new instance of Carousel
var carousel = new Carousel('#frame', '#slider', '#slider .slide', '.arrowLeft', '.arrowRight');
```

And need to adjust it to:

1. Make next arrow disappear when slider reaches the last slide.
2. Make previous arrow not appear when slider is on first slide.
3. Make the first next button transition smooth - now for some reason first next transition is instant. Here is video https://puu.sh/xNko8/694e2439c2.mp4

Comment: (offtopic) I don't know where you've found that code but it's not the way to build slide galleries... The way it uses `new` makes absolutely no sense since the instance is useless as the code is not written for reusability and multiple galleries on a single page... Fixed hardcoded value sizes (like `250` and stuff) are odd... Fixing the above code would be a miss overall :(

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, thank you for your comment. Would [this pen](https://codepen.io/gety9/pen/MEvMZO) be better option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you can ***add jquery*** to **manipulate simply the DOM** in this example i use the **limit width** of your slider and **if this superior** **then** **append the slider to the end of the parent**  here simple example based on your but need to be adapted of your needs.

```
var moveSlide = function (value) {
    leftPosition += value*250;
    slider.style.left = leftPosition + 'px';
    //console.log(parseInt(slider.style.left));
    if(parseInt(slider.style.left) <= (-1000)){
      //console.log("do split");       
      $("#slider div[class^='slider-box']").clone().appendTo($("#slider"));
    }
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WZERGw
     };

Answer (score 0):

Transition is not working on first click because you don't have a default left property in slider. Just add left: 0px and transition will work even on first click.

For making arrows disappear, fetch left property of slider using javascript. Same way you can handle right as well.